# Data binding on input element not working with wrapper class

Tags: visualforce, databinding

I'm trying to capture input from the user on a visualforce page, but on save the value of the property (myLoanWrap.Amoritization) does not reflect the input value the user enters on the UI, what am I missing? Here's the code:

Input binds to **myLoanWrap.Amoritization**

**VF Page**

```
<apex:form>
<div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-2">
    <!-- Amoritization -->
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-amortization">Amoritization (months)</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <apex:inputText id="input-amortization" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!myLoanWrap.Amoritization}"/>
            
            <!-- <input id="input-amortization" class="slds-input" type="number" value="{!myLoanWrap.Amoritization}"  /> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Save Button

```
<apex:define name="right">
    <apex:form>
        <!-- Save & Continue Button -->
        <apex:commandButton id="saveButton" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" 
        action="{!savePaymentDetails}" value="Save & Continue" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:define>
```

**Controller - cm_PaymentInfoRouteController**

```
public cm_LoanModel myLoanWrap {get;set;}

public cm_PaymentInfoRouteController() {
        
        //Show loading spinner as the page loads its content
        loadingSpinnerIsActive = true;

        //Get current record id
        this.loanId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

        //Check if test class is running
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            getLoanDetail();
        }

        //Hide loading spinner
        loadingSpinnerIsActive = false;
    }

private void getLoanDetail() {

        //Get loan payment attributes
        myLoanWrap = new cm_LoanModel(loanId);

        //Render the fixed or variable rate component based on selected rate type
        renderRateTypeComponent(myLoanWrap.RateType);

    }

public PageReference savePaymentDetails() { 
        
        system.debug('xxxxx: Save button was clicked!');
        system.debug('save --- amortization: ' + myLoanWrap.Amoritization);
        system.debug('save --- pay frequency: ' + myLoanWrap.PaymentFrequency);

        //Update loan record with payment summary details
        myLoanWrap.updateLoanPaymentDetails();

        return null;
    }
```

**Model-cm_LoanModel**

```
public with sharing class cm_LoanModel {
    
    //Loan Variable
    private List<LLC_BI__Loan__c> loanDetail;

    //Loan Attributes
    public Decimal TotalFinancedAmount {get; set;}
    public String TotalFinancedAmountFormatted {get; set;}
    public Decimal Amoritization {get; set;}
    public Decimal Term {get; set;}
    public String PaymentFrequency {get; set;}
    public String PaymentType {get; set;}
    public String RateType {get; set;}
    public Decimal QualifyingRate {get; set;}
    public Decimal PostedBasisRate {get; set;}
    public Decimal PostedBasisAdjustment {get; set;}
    public Decimal NetRate {get; set;}
    public String NetRateFormatted {get; set;}

    
    public cm_LoanModel(String id) {

        //Query Loan record
        queryLoan(id);
    }

    public void queryLoan (String loanID) {

        loanDetail = [SELECT Name, cm_Total_Financed_Amount__c, LLC_BI__Amount__c, cm_Total_Financed_Charged_Fees__c, LLC_BI__Amortized_Term_Months__c, 
        LLC_BI__Payment_Schedule__c, LLC_BI__Payment_Type__c, LLC_BI__Pricing_Basis__c, LLC_BI__Rate_Discount__c, LLC_BI__InterestRate__c, LLC_BI__Term_Months__c
        FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c 
        WHERE  Id =: loanID LIMIT 1];
        
        if(!loanDetail.isEmpty()) {
            
            System.debug('xxxxxx Loan Detail: ' + loanDetail);

            for(LLC_BI__Loan__c queriedLoan : loanDetail) {
                //Set Loan Attributes
                this.TotalFinancedAmount = queriedLoan.cm_Total_Financed_Amount__c;
                this.TotalFinancedAmountFormatted = '$' + (TotalFinancedAmount.format().contains('.')?TotalFinancedAmount.format():(TotalFinancedAmount.format()+'.00'));
                
                this.Amoritization = queriedLoan.LLC_BI__Amortized_Term_Months__c;
                this.Term = queriedLoan.LLC_BI__Term_Months__c;

                this.PaymentFrequency = queriedLoan.LLC_BI__Payment_Schedule__c;
                this.PaymentType = queriedLoan.LLC_BI__Payment_Type__c;

                this.RateType = (String)queriedLoan.LLC_BI__Pricing_Basis__c;
                //this.QualifyingRate = 4.53;

                //this.PostedBasisRate = queriedLoan.LLC_BI__Pricing_Basis__c;
                this.PostedBasisAdjustment = queriedLoan.LLC_BI__Rate_Discount__c;
                this.NetRate = queriedLoan.LLC_BI__InterestRate__c;
                this.NetRateFormatted = (NetRate.format().contains('.')?NetRate.format():(NetRate.format()+'.00')) + '%';
            }
        }
        else {
            System.debug('ERROR: The loan record was not found! Loan ID: ' + loanID); 
        }
    }

    public void updateLoanPaymentDetails () {
        try {

            //Update the queried loan record
            for(LLC_BI__Loan__c queriedLoan : loanDetail) {
                
                queriedLoan.LLC_BI__Amortized_Term_Months__c = this.Amoritization;

            }

            update loanDetail;
        }
        catch(DmlException e) {
            System.debug('Error in class cm_LoanModel.updateLoanPaymentDetails: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**Moved the command button under the same apex form as the input element**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have used **two `forms`**. Combine your `command button` in the same form and it should work fine. Command buttons takes form as the context, if the form does not have any reference it would return null.

```
public cm_PaymentInfoRouteController(){
    myLoanWrap = new cm_LoanModel();
}
```

Tested with :

```
public class cm_PaymentInfoRouteController {
    public TestWrapper myLoanWrap {get;set;}

    public cm_PaymentInfoRouteController(){
        myLoanWrap = new TestWrapper();
    }

    public PageReference savePaymentDetails() {

        system.debug('xxxxx: Save button was clicked!');
        system.debug('save --- amortization: ' + myLoanWrap.Amoritization);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Page :

```
<apex:page id="testPage" controller="cm_PaymentInfoRouteController">
    <apex:form>
        <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-2">
            <!-- Amoritization -->
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-amortization">Amoritization (months)</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <apex:inputText id="input-amortization" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!myLoanWrap.Amoritization}"/>

                    <!-- <input id="input-amortization" class="slds-input" type="number" value="{!myLoanWrap.Amoritization}"  /> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <apex:commandButton id="saveButton" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                            action="{!savePaymentDetails}" value="Save & Continue" />
    </apex:form>
    <apex:define name="right">
        <apex:form>
            <!-- Save & Continue Button -->

        </apex:form>
    </apex:define>
</apex:page>
```

Wrapper :

```
global class TestWrapper {

    public Decimal Amoritization {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I moved the command button under the same form but I'm still not getting anything.. see the attached picture in the post

Comment: As i dont have access to your full code, i have given an example of what i have tried and it works fine. Please check the form which i have created and button which i have placed.